# Select input keyboard type for QLineEdit

Tags: android, qt

Basically I need the feature that is documented here: http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

I need to specify input type for `QLineEdit`, specifically I need to set it to number keyboard input.

[image: keyboard input image]

I can't find anything in Qt documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QLineEdit::setInputMethodHints` and try [hints](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qt.html#InputMethodHint-enum) like `Qt::ImhPreferNumbers`, `Qt::ImhDigitsOnly` or `Qt::ImhFormattedNumbersOnly` or `ImhDialableCharactersOnly`.

Comment: Sounds like the exact thing I need! Let me test it before I accept the answer.

Comment: I'm sure one of those hints should work, but I can't test It right now, sorry. There were also some bugs in Qt 4.8 and older.